# How to index geojson file in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson, shapefile

I am trying to store spatial data in the form of geojson,csv files and shape files into elasticsearch USING PYTHON.I am new to elasticsearch and even after following the documentation i am not able to successfully index it. Any help would be appreciated.

sample geojson file :

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID_0": 105,
        "ISO": "IND",
        "NAME_0": "India",
        "ID_1": 1288,
        "NAME_1": "Telangana",
        "ID_2": 15715,
        "NAME_2": "Telangana",
        "VARNAME_2": null,
        "NL_NAME_2": null,
        "HASC_2": "IN.TS.AD",
        "CC_2": null,
        "TYPE_2": "State",
        "ENGTYPE_2": "State",
        "VALIDFR_2": "Unknown",
        "VALIDTO_2": "Present",
        "REMARKS_2": null,
        "Shape_Leng": 8.103535,
        "Shape_Area": 127258717496
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              79.14429367552918,
              19.500257885106404
            ],
            [
              79.14582245808431,
              19.498859172536427
            ],
            [
              79.14600496956801,
              19.498823981691853
            ],
            [
              79.14966523737327,
              19.495821705263914
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your geojson file? (or part of it)

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":
[{"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"ID_0":105,"ISO":"IND","NAME_0":"India","ID_1":1288,"NAME_1":"Telangana","ID_2":15715,"NAME_2":"Telangana","VARNAME_2":null,"NL_NAME_2":null,"HASC_2":"IN.TS.AD","CC_2":null,"TYPE_2":"State","ENGTYPE_2":"State","VALIDFR_2":"Unknown","VALIDTO_2":"Present","REMARKS_2":null,"Shape_Leng":8.103535,"Shape_Area":127258717496},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[79.14429367552918,19.500257885106404],[79.14582245808431,19.498859172536427],[79.14600496956801,19.498823981691853],

Comment: Please update your question with it

Comment: It's funny, I just read the documentation on [elasticsearch.co](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-geo-shapes.html) and indeed the chapter "How to index geosjon file..." does only show a geojson document, but not how to index it.

Comment: @intern did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

### Code

```
import geojson
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers


def geojson_to_es(gj):

    for feature in gj['features']:

        date = datetime.strptime("-".join(feature["properties"]["event_date"].split('-')[0:2]) + "-" + feature["properties"]["year"], "%d-%b-%Y")
        feature["properties"]["timestamp"] = int(date.timestamp())
        feature["properties"]["event_date"] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        yield feature


with open("GeoObs.json") as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

    k = ({
        "_index": "YOUR_INDEX",
        "_source": feature,
    } for feature in geojson_to_es(gj))

    helpers.bulk(es, k)
```

### Explanation

```
with open("GeoObs.json") as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
```

This portion of the code loads an external geojson file, then connects to Elasticsearch.

```
    k = ({
        "_index": "conflict-data",
        "_source": feature,
    } for feature in geojson_to_es(gj))

    helpers.bulk(es, k)
```

The `()`s here creates a generator which we will feed to `helpers.bulk(es, k)`. Remember `_source` is the original data as is in Elasticsearch speak - IE: our raw JSON. `_index` is just the index in which we want to put our data. You'll see other examples with `_doc` here. This is part of the mapping types and no longer exists in Elasticsearch 7.X+.

```
def geojson_to_es(gj):

    for feature in gj['features']:

        date = datetime.strptime("-".join(feature["properties"]["event_date"].split('-')[0:2]) + "-" + feature["properties"]["year"], "%d-%b-%Y")
        feature["properties"]["timestamp"] = int(date.timestamp())
        feature["properties"]["event_date"] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        yield feature
```

The function `geojson` uses a generator to produce events. A generator function will, instead of returning and finishing`resume at the keyword`yield` after each call. In this case, we are generating our GeoJSON features. In my code you also see:

```
date = datetime.strptime("-".join(feature["properties"]["event_date"].split('-')[0:2]) + "-" + feature["properties"]["year"], "%d-%b-%Y")
feature["properties"]["timestamp"] = int(date.timestamp())
feature["properties"]["event_date"] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This is just an example of manipulating the data in the JSON before sending it out to Elasticsearch.

**The key is in your mapping file** you must have something tagged as `geo_point` or `geo_shape`. These data types are how Elasticsearch recognizes geo data. Example from my mapping file:

```
...
{
  "properties": {
    "geometry": {
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
...
```

That is to say, before uploading your GeoJSON data with Python, you need to create your index, and then apply a mapping file which includes either `geo_shape` or `geo_point` using something like:

`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX?pretty"`
`curl -X PUT localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX/_mapping?pretty -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @mapping.json`

Answer (score 0):

You must separate the GeoJson features into (1) geometry and (2) properties/attributes parts. You cannot index GeoJson features and feature collections directly ([see documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html)), only the *geometry part* is supported as a field type.

So you final indexable document would look somewhat flattened:

```
{
    "ID_0": 105,
    "ISO": "IND",
    "NAME_0": "India",
    "ID_1": 1288,
    "NAME_1": "Telangana",
    "ID_2": 15715,
    "NAME_2": "Telangana",
    "VARNAME_2": null,
    "NL_NAME_2": null,
    "HASC_2": "IN.TS.AD",
    "CC_2": null,
    "TYPE_2": "State",
    "ENGTYPE_2": "State",
    "VALIDFR_2": "Unknown",
    "VALIDTO_2": "Present",
    "REMARKS_2": null,
    "Shape_Leng": 8.103535,
    "Shape_Area": 127258717496,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    79.14429367552918,
                    19.500257885106404
                ],
                [
                    79.14582245808431,
                    19.498859172536427
                ],
                [
                    79.14600496956801,
                    19.498823981691853
                ],
                [
                    79.14966523737327,
                    19.495821705263914
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Answered long ago, but if anyone's reading; Is there a data type for "Shape_Area" or Leng? Do I just use a float/long or Point ?

Comment: No special type for these - you should stick to plain numeric types in ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html

Comment: How would you actually do the indexing of the data though?