# geojson to Elasticsearch : Failed to parse field [geometry.coordinates] of type [geo_shape]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, geojson

I am trying to indexing geojson file into elasticsearch (version 7.6.2) using Python.

Here is the mapping I defined in elasticsearch.

```
'mappings': {
  "properties": {
    "geometry": {
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "geo_shape"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },    
 }
}
```

The geojson file looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "testting",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "LEGEND": "x_1", "THRESHOLD": -109, "COLOR": "0 0 255", "Prediction": "Coverage" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 151.20061069847705, -33.886918725260998 ], [ 151.200620164862698, -33.886467994010133 ].....
```

However, when I write the file to Elasticsearch, inspired from this link:

[How to index geojson file in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129634/how-to-index-geojson-file-in-elasticsearch)

```
def geojson2es(gj):
    for feature in gj['features']:
        yield feature

with open(input_path+'/'+ data) as f:
    gj = json.load(f)

    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

    k = [{
        "_index": "test",
        "_source": feature,
    } for feature in geojson2es(gj)]

    helpers.bulk(es, k)
```

I have got this error:

**{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 
'reason': 'failed to parse field [geometry.coordinates] of type [geo_shape]', '
caused_by': 
{'type': 'parse_exception', 'reason': 'shape must be an object consisting of type and coordinates'}}**

Did anyone encounter a similar issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is not correct. The [`geo_shape` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) already implies `type` and `coordinates`, so you don't need to declare them again.

So your mapping should be like this instead, i.e. each feature has a `type` (e.g. `Feature`, a hash of `properties` and a `geometry` of type `geo_shape`):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "properties": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't there a problem that in type `FeatureCollection` we actually have an ARRAY of features? in the mappings it seems like we declare a single feature, not an array...

Comment: @OhadR Feel free to create a new question with your specific use case/question

Comment: thanks. actually it is very similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761480/featurecollection-to-geo-shape-in-elasticsearch so i dont wanna ask a similar question again. just asking about your answer here - how the fact that `FeatureCollection` is an array is reflected? thanks for the responsiveness!

Comment: There's no array type in Elasticsearch. You simply declare an object in the mapping and then you're free to index an array of those objects